# Created a hidden folder, now the files are missing

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit, user-folders

I have a hidden `bin` folder, this morning I came in and was saving a script and got the whole `access denied` thing. So I checked out my folder, made it unhidden, etc.. All the sub-folders, files, scripts, etc.. Are now gone. However, I can still cd into the folders, once in the folders, it says there's nothing there and that it's an empty folder.

Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Is there any clue as to what happened or any way I can get my files and folders back?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that the hidden attribute was with all of the files, so what I needed to do was `attrib -h *.* /S /D` all my folders are back, and we're good to go.